# How to fail during maven copy-resources instead skip non existing resourceDirectory when perform maven-resources-plugin:copy-resources

Tags: maven, resources

How to fail on maven copy-resources instead skip non existing resourceDirectory when perform maven-resources-plugin:copy-resources

I have config as descibed here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy-root-configuration-files) @ replicator ---
[INFO] Using 'uft-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory ....
[INFO]
```

How to fail instead skipping non existing resourceDirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resource plugin doesn't help you there. Try the http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin/ instead or the [enforcer plugin with `requireFilesExist`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html)

The latter works better for multi-module builds if you want the same check for every module. Just add the check to the parent POM.

Comment: To add to this, make sure your packages are named correctly. A simple `Test` -> `test` naming change of my package fixed this issue for me. (It had only happened after migrating from a Mac agent to a Linux agent)